# Can a truecrypt container be moved on Fedora Linux?

Tags: truecrypt

I have created a truecrypt container (100GB) to store very important files with vital information hidden on my hardrive running Fedora Linux OS.

Now, I want to move the container to portable hardrive. From what I read so far, you should be able to do it easily like any other file. However, I am running into problem. Fedora won't let me. It keeps giving me "Permission denied" error. I think I need to login as a root or superuser, but how do you do that on Fedora.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you unmount your truecrypt volume before trying to move the container?

Comment: Yes it is unmount. The file itself has X and a lock icon over it.

Comment: Did you create the file using sudo? I'd recommend running `sudo chown <username> <filename>` to give yourself ownership of the file.

Comment: I used the GUI truecrypt program...

Comment: Could you see who owns the file (right-click and properties) and what permissions you have on the file.

Comment: Owner - has full read / write access. User -  has full read/write access. Others - read only. I am logged in as a user and created the container within this user account.

Comment: And the same user is owner of this file? Weird. The truecrypt files i create i'm owner and don't have a lock in the file-icon. I do think we need the result of a `ls -l /home/user_name/Documents/truecrypt_filename` to see exactly what is going on with the file. You can open a terminal and type the command.

Comment: this is the result of that command -rw-------. 1 root root 107374182400

Comment: That means that the owner (root) has read/write access, but no one else. Try `sudo chown <username> <filename>` as DanteTheEgregore mentioned.

Comment: okay I did, then what...what is the exact command to change the owner from root to user?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the container was created by the truecrypt program under root.

After executing the following command-line in the terminal, the file's owner changed to user.

sudo chown

Of course, you should be within the folder the file is located or provide the path to the file in the command-line.

thanks,